# How to call the date picker function when focus on textbox from Jquery-UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When focus on the text box the date picker should appear. That date picker should have the year option.

This is what first I tried to show the date picker dialog box. But I don't know what i did wrong in it.

i think i did a mistake on the header file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#datepick").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus(function () {
                    $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker("show");
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to show the year option as well.

I saw this [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnUWQ/embedded/result/). But I don't know why it doesn't work in my case.

**Updated**

> **Error message**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
 at Datepicker._get (jquery-ui.js:8633)
 at Datepicker._showDatepicker (jquery-ui.js:7910)
 at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:9256)
 at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:368)
 at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:157)
 at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui.js:9253)
 at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (test.aspx:36)
 at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5202)
 at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5010)
 at HTMLInputElement.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.js:5325)
```

Comment: do you have any errors ?

Comment: @BigDong yes. I got the error on console. I will update now

Comment: Apparently you are trying to read `settings` within an object that is undefined. This doesn't come from the code you are showing. Aren't you supposed to configure the datepicker somewhere ?  Otherwise, I guess you will have to provide a runnable example

Comment: @bigdong Yes now i got that date picker dialog box. But it's not showing the left and right arrows. Image not found error message is occur in this location css/images/ui-icons. But i have those images on images folder

Comment: @BigDong finally I add the images too. Can you help me how to add the year dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my solution by myself.

This is the answer for my questions.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth:true
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus(function () {
                    $("#datepick").datepicker("show");
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus();
            });
        </script>
```